# Returning an objects subclass with generics

Tags: java, generics, subclass, parameterized, return-type

With an abstract class I want to define a method that returns "this" for the subclasses:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    ...
    public <T extends Foo> T eat(String eatCake) {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}  

public class Eater extends Foo {}
```

I want to be able to do things like:

```
Eater phil = new Eater();
phil.eat("wacky cake").eat("chocolate cake").eat("banana bread");
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends Foo<T>>  // see ColinD's comment
{
    public T eat(String eatCake) 
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class CakeEater extends Foo<CakeEater> 
{
    public void f(){}
}
```

Edit

There is no problem to require subclass behave in a certain way that's beyond what static typing can check. We do that all the time - pages and pages of plain english to specify how you write a subclass.

The other proposed solution, with covariant return type, must do the same - asking subclass implementers, in plain english, to return the type of `this`. That requirement cannot be specified by static typing.

Comment: Should be `Foo<T extends Foo<T>>`. This works, though you can easily make a class that will blow up with a `ClassCastException` when you call `eat`, such as `class Bar extends Foo<CakeEater>`.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, but you'll notice that the return has an unchecked cast warning. While logically it makes sense that we can cast to T as this is a subclass of T.

Comment: Yes. In a better world, Java could have a `This` type, which would be very useful in a lot of cases.

Comment: `class FakeEater extends Foo<CakeEater> { }` Now take notice of the warning.

Comment: Tom, I didn't notice any warning. Maybe that's the point of your response, that there is no compile time warning. When calling FakeEater's eat there will be a a compile-time exception that the returning type is not of type FakeEater if it is being assigned to a FakeEater field.

Comment: Could you store an instance of the subclass's class in the superclass? Maybe make in mandatory in the abstract class constructor. Calling clazz.cast(this) will then perform a typesafe cast back to the subclass type, won't it?

Answer (score 25):

The tasteful approach from the client point of view (which is usually the one you want to take) is to use covariant return types which was added to support generics, as Michael Barker points out.

The slightly less tasteful, but more tasteful that a cast is to add a `getThis` method:

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
    protected abstract T getThis();

    public T eat(String eatCake) {
        ...
        return getThis();
    }
}

public class CakeEater extends Foo<CakeEater> {
    @Override protected CakeEater getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tom. Why slightly less? yours is DRY, right?

Comment: @Arash It adds weirdo generics and a protected method to the interface, neither of which are tasteful. Though the alternative of overriding with a covariant return type does leave a load of rubbish of the form `@Override public CakeEater eat(String eatCake) { super.eat(SeatCake); return this; }`, which may be missed out when the base class is updated..

Comment: Thanks @Tom. Yes that's right. but i like generics with `getThis()` approach; it's safer ( I did not know till I read your answer ). Unfortunately i have to override because i couldn't find a way to do `child.eatParent().eatMyself()`.

Comment: **It's never more "tasteful" to duplacate each and every method** of super-class. just to change return-type (covariant return types are not meant for builder-style sub-classes).

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you need generics Java 5 (and later) has covariant return types, e.g.:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    ...
    public Foo eat(String eatCake) {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}  

public class CakeEater extends Foo {

    public CakeEater eat(String eatCake) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's fully defined in the superclass then it creates redundant code to define it in the subclass; It could call the superclass but this seems unnecessary. It works if you cast this as type T and suppress warnings.

Comment: It works if you cast this as type T and suppress warnings.

The reason it should be return the type of the subclass is because:

    methodTakesCakeEater( (new CakeEater).eat("cake").eat("pie");

methodTakesCakeEater needs a CakeEater parameter.

Comment: If a solution contains `@SuppressWarnings` it shouldn't be considered a solution. Just my two cents.

Comment: don't worry about warnings when you are doing edgy stuff.

Comment: I do not think this is a good solution to the sketched problem because it requires one to override all methods in the subclass, hardly worth the effort. The idea is to have a fluent API that subclasses can leverage, not rewrite.

Comment: I also do not think this is "edgy" stuff requiring one to ignore or suppress warnings

Comment: Coming back to this from the future, the overridden `eat` method should call `super.eat` (and ignore the return value). Also perhaps add `@Override` - I'm not sure that was even possible for overridden abstract methods for versions of Java in common use when this answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

An approach I've used before to achieve similar behaviour is to have the subclass pass its type into a constructor of the (generified) parent type. By way of disclaimer I was generating the subclasses on the fly and inheritence was a bit of a cheat to keep my code generation simple, as always my first instinct is to try to remove the extends relationship altogether.