# java return abstract class in abstract method

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I got some problem with java's interfaces and abstract classes.
I have interface

```
public interface IVector <T extends  IVector>{
   public IVector add(IVector vector);
   public IVector sub(IVector vector);
   public double dotProduct(IVector vector);
   public IVector scalar(double scalar);
}
```

and `abstract class` like this:

```
public abstract class Vector implements IVector{
   final ArrayList<Double> coordinates;

   public Vector(ArrayList<Double> list){
      coordinates = list;
   }

   public IVector add(Vector v){
      ArrayList<Double> newCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
      if (v.coordinates.size() == this.coordinates.size()){
         for (int i = 0; i < this.coordinates.size(); i++) {
            newCoordinates.add(v.coordinates.get(i)+this.coordinates.get(i));
         }
      }
      else return null;
      return new IVector(newCoordinates);
  }
```

Its just addition of vectors with n coordinates, how can i return result? I wanna use child classes (like 2dVector or 3dVector) in future?

Comment: Why do you use raw types? If you wouldn't you would already have your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning an objects subclass with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284610/returning-an-objects-subclass-with-generics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create an abstract object directly - you need concrete class or override the required methods defined by the abstract.

Something like this may be what you are looking for.

```
public interface IVector<T extends IVector> {
    public T add(T vector);

    public T sub(T vector);

    public double dotProduct(T vector);

    public T scalar(double scalar);
}

public abstract class Vector<T extends Vector> implements IVector<T> {
    final ArrayList<Double> coordinates;

    public Vector(ArrayList<Double> list) {
        coordinates = list;
    }

}

public class AVector extends Vector<AVector> {
    public AVector(ArrayList<Double> list) {
        super(list);
    }

    @Override
    public AVector add(AVector v) {
        ArrayList<Double> newCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (v.coordinates.size() == this.coordinates.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.coordinates.size(); i++) {
                newCoordinates.add(v.coordinates.get(i) + this.coordinates.get(i));
            }
        } else return null;
        return new AVector(newCoordinates);
    }

    @Override
    public AVector sub(AVector vector) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public double dotProduct(AVector vector) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public AVector scalar(double scalar) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Note that using `public abstract class Vector implements IVector` in your code introduces `Raw Types` and should be avoided. Notice I have used `public abstract class Vector<T extends Vector> implements IVector<T>` instead.

To achieve your aim of making the `add` method generic to all `Vector` objects as you seem to be trying to do you need some form of factory method.

Something like this may be a fair attempt at that.

```
public interface IVector<T extends IVector> {
    public T add(T vector);

}

public interface Factory<T> {
    public T makeNew (ArrayList<Double> coordinates);
}

public abstract class Vector<T extends Vector<T> & Factory<T>> implements IVector<T> {
    final ArrayList<Double> coordinates;

    public Vector(ArrayList<Double> list) {
        coordinates = list;
    }

    @Override
    public T add(T v) {
        if (v.coordinates.size() == this.coordinates.size()) {
            ArrayList<Double> newCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.coordinates.size(); i++) {
                newCoordinates.add(v.coordinates.get(i) + this.coordinates.get(i));
            }
            // Use the passed parameter as a factory.
            return v.makeNew(coordinates);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public class AVector extends Vector<AVector> implements Factory<AVector> {
    public AVector(ArrayList<Double> list) {
        super(list);
    }

    @Override
    public AVector makeNew(ArrayList<Double> coordinates) {
        return new AVector(coordinates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class cannot be instantiated: nor can an interface. You have to return either a subclass of `Vector` or an implementation of `IVector`.